# Python: How to compare time in 24 Hrs format

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime-format

I am stuck with this tricky part with time manipulation:-

`start_time = 22.00.00`  -------------[10pm]

`end_time = 05.00.00` ---------[5.0am]

`current_time = 01.00.00` -----------[1am]

Here, I want to verify my current time is between start and end time.

This line of condition does not work here:-

```
if start_time < current_time < end_time:    
     DO THIS
```

How am I suppose to handle this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your time strings are in `HH.MM.SS` format, you can compare them directly as strings. However you need to take account of the fact that the period might span a 24-hour boundary, so that `end_time < start_time`. In that scenario you need to reverse the compare and invert the result.

```py
start_time = "22.00.00"
end_time = "05.00.00"
current_time = "01.00.00"

if start_time < end_time and start_time < current_time < end_time or \
   end_time < start_time and not (end_time < current_time < start_time):
    # do this!
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a straightforward universal solution you can use `datetime.datetime.strptime` like this

```js
#!/usr/bin/env python
import datetime

start_time = "22.00.00"
end_time = "05.00.00"
current_time = "01.00.00"

start_dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_time, "%H.%M.%S")
end_dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(end_time, "%H.%M.%S")
current_dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(current_time, "%H.%M.%S")

if start_dt < current_dt < end_dt:
    print("wahoo!")
else:
    print("wrong")
```

```html
<script src="https://modularizer.github.io/pyprez/pyprez.min.js"></script>
```

However, there is actually a less readable yet **faster way** to do it which avoids  actually analyzing the date, which is you to make a number from the strings like this.

```js
#!/usr/bin/env python
start_time = "22.00.00"
end_time = "05.00.00"
current_time = "01.00.00"

if int(start_time.replace(".","")) < int(current_time.replace(".","")) < int(end_time.replace(".","")):
    print("wahoo!")
else:
    print("wrong")
```

```html
<script src="https://modularizer.github.io/pyprez/pyprez.min.js"></script>
```